# Compile error:... was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, eigen

I'm a neophyte of C++ programmation. I have to implement a program witch calculates the pseudoinverse of a matrix. As the Eigen tutorial suggests, I have written a code like this:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <Core>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <Eigen/Dense>
    #include <Eigen/SVD>
    #include <Eigen/Eigen>
    using namespace Eigen;
    using namespace std;



    void pinv(MatrixXf& pinvmat)
     {
    ei_assert(m_isInitialized && "SVD is not initialized.");
   double  pinvtoler=1.e-6;                       // choose tolerance 
    SingularValuesType m_sigma_inv=m_sigma;
    for ( long i=0; i<m_workMatrix.cols(); ++i) {
    if ( m_sigma(i) > pinvtoler )
     m_sigma_inv(i)=1.0/m_sigma(i);
   else m_sigma_inv(i)=0;
   }
    pinvmat = (m_matV*m_sigma_inv.asDiagonal()*m_matU.transpose());


   }

    int main()
   {

    MatrixXf A(3,2);
    A<<1,2,3,4,5,6;
    pinv(A);
    cout << "pinv =" << endl << A << endl;
    return 0;
   }
```

If I try to compile it I'll get the errors:

```
tut_eigen/pinv.cpp: In function ‘void pinv(Eigen::MatrixXf&)’:
tut_eigen/pinv.cpp:18:14: error: ‘m_isInitialized’ was not declared in this scope
tut_eigen/pinv.cpp:18:58: error: ‘ei_assert’ was not declared in this scope
tut_eigen/pinv.cpp:20:4: error: ‘SingularValuesType’ was not declared in this scope
tut_eigen/pinv.cpp:20:23: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘m_sigma_inv’
tut_eigen/pinv.cpp:21:22: error: ‘m_workMatrix’ was not declared in this scope
tut_eigen/pinv.cpp:22:19: error: ‘m_sigma’ was not declared in this scope
tut_eigen/pinv.cpp:23:19: error: ‘m_sigma_inv’ was not declared in this scope
tut_eigen/pinv.cpp:24:22: error: ‘m_sigma_inv’ was not declared in this scope
tut_eigen/pinv.cpp:26:15: error: ‘m_matV’ was not declared in this scope
tut_eigen/pinv.cpp:26:22: error: ‘m_sigma_inv’ was not declared in this scope
tut_eigen/pinv.cpp:26:47: error: ‘m_matU’ was not declared in this scope
```

Why?? They are not declared in SVD file?

Comment: Using the `m_` prefix on variables are typically used for _class member variables_. Some of these variables (like `m_sigma`) are not declared anywhere.

Comment: Where are m_sigma , m_sigma_inv, m_isInitialized etc, declared?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you talk about this ["tutorial"](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=FAQ#Is_there_a_method_to_compute_the_.28Moore-Penrose.29_pseudo_inverse_.3F) which isn't so much a tutorial but an FAQ assuming you know a bit about the library already (it would be helpful if you link to your sources of information, BTW).

What this says is that you can add the `pinv()` method to the `SVD` "from the outside". I assume they mean that you can derive from `SVD` and provide the `pinv()` method in your derived class. Just typing the function somewhere doesn't give the compiler the necessary context to determine where referenced names are located.